# rotated minimum area rectangle with OpenCV

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

Hi I am trying to implement the following code from [Detection and Recognition of Painted Road Surface Markings](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8685/15a108dce3b6ba9aa3e7b2ec9a7b57487f00.pdf). They are talking about ***rotated minimum area rectangle (RMAR)*** in the paper

I am wondering would this be the same as using 
`cv::minAreaRect(whateverblotsyouhave)`

Which will return you a `RotatedRect` class which has a field properties area? Would they be the same? I really could not tell the difference

How are the two different? Is there some `algorithm` or `code` for it?

Comment: I do not see any difference, either.

Comment: Some function annotations in OpenCV sources contain links to algorithm descriptions or papers.

Comment: @MBo Unfortunately, I don't see anything in this case: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/94758c18de7b404fce44b0f2e11d2a321c1e086f/modules/imgproc/src/rotcalipers.cpp#L347

Comment: @MBo do you mean the fitellipse.cpp in the demo? but i seriously do not see how